# Update()の中で色を変える処理（material.color）を行うと、なぜかスルーされます。

Tags: unity3d

以下のように、
Start()の中で、色を変える処理を行うと、できるのですが

Update()の中でおこなうとスルーされ、処理がおこなれません
ちなみに位置の取得はできました。

また、色情報を取得したところ、Debug.Logでは色を変えた状態で取得できました。
ただ、実行結果（画面）は色が変わらないままでした。

分かる方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class BattleMain : BattleBase {

    protected int _sceneTask;
    //public GameObject prefab = (GameObject) Resources.Load("Object/MassTile");
    public GameObject prefab = null;
    public GameObject[,] mass = new GameObject[15,15];
    int isk;
    int jsk;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        // 配置するプレハブの読み込み 
        //GameObject prefab = (GameObject) Resources.Load("Object/MassTile");
        // 配置元のオブジェクト指定 
        GameObject stageObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("Stage");
        //// タイル配置
        for(int i = 0; i < 15 ; i ++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 15 ; j ++) {


                Vector3 tile_pos = new Vector3(
                    0 + prefab.transform.localScale.x * i,
                    0,
                    0 + prefab.transform.localScale.z * j

                    );

                if(prefab != null){
                    // プレハブの複製 
                    GameObject instant_object = Instantiate(prefab,tile_pos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                    // 生成元の下に複製したプレハブをくっつける 
                    instant_object.transform.parent = stageObject.transform;
                    mass[i,j] = instant_object;
                }
            }
        }
        int Ivent = Random.Range(4, 7);//ランダムにイベントマスの設置
        for(int p = 0; p < Ivent;p++){
        int iRandNum = Random.Range(0, 14);
        int jRandNum = Random.Range(0, 14);
        mass[iRandNum,jRandNum].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(0.2f, 0.8f, 0.9f, 0.5f);
        }


    }


    // Update is called once per frame

    void Update(){
        mass[5,5].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        Debug.Log (mass [5, 5].GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color);
        mass [1, 5].GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = new Color (0.2f, 0.8f, 0.9f, 0.5f);
        Debug.Log (mass [1, 5].GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color);
    }


}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

Unity 5.3.1 ですが、意図してる通りに 5,5 の位置のマスが黒くなりました。
もしかして同じオブジェクトに複数の BattleMain がアタッチされてますか？

```
this.btm = this.gameObject.GetComponent<BattleMain>();
```

この記述が不思議で、普通だったら this.btm == this になるはずです。
試しに、↓これで動くでしょうか？

```
void Update(){
//    btm.SyuIti ();//スルーされる
    SyuIti ();
}
```

Comment: あと、スクリプトとスクリーンショットは別のもののようですが、もしかして「Update()」の綴り間違えとかではないですよね・・。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
初心者ゆえ、そんな簡単にメソッド呼びだができるなんて
知りませんでした。ありがとうございます。

void Update(){
//    btm.SyuIti ();//スルーされる
    SyuIti ();
}
でも結果は同じでした。

スクリプトに関しては複数のスクリプトを扱っています、
しかし、色塗りがスルーされたUpdate()内に
色の取得
（Debug.Log (mass [1, 5].GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color);）
などを追加すると正常に処理されました。
色塗り酒できない、なそです・・・・・泣

また、複数のスクリプトをアタッチしていることもありませんでした。
もうちょっともがいてみます。